# Discord Python Bot crashes after 24 hours

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Long story short, I have this happy little python discord bot running on my raspberry pi and it works absolutely perfectly, the problem is that after a while, the bot seems to encounter connection issues and therefore crash, I'm not really sure what could be causing it

Python Console Error:

```
File "connector.py", line 314, in connect
.format(key, exc.strerror)) from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError: [Errno 10051] Cannot connect to host  discordapp.com:443 ssl:True [Can not connect to discordapp.com:xxx [Connect  call failed ('xxx.xx.xx.x', xxx)]]
```

From what I can tell, it has issues in keeping a stable connection with the discord API, again, when I first start the bot it's fine and works perfectly but after a few hours that error occurs, I will greatly appreciate someone's help

Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend you hosting your bot on [Heroku](https://heroku.com) or another platform, here is an example [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wal2taXZEAY) that shows you how to host it on heroku

Comment: I assume you have to start a subscription with that service to host the bot so if it's possible to fix the problem (which im sure it is) then paying is really not worth it...

Comment: Heroku has a hobby plan in which you can get around 450 hours of host time per month, it's better than your bot to keep crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I have never really seen this issue on a Discord bot before. I recommend hosting your bot with [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com). It provides a free plan which allows you to host your bot without any change. Hope that helps!